# SDL_Mixer Mix_LoadWAV can not find RIFF or WAVE identifiers

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2, sdl-mixer

I have asked this before since december but was ignored everywhere so I am trying to ask this one last time.

I am trying to load [an audio file](https://easyupload.io/1smtes) (as an Mix_Chunk) but I am getting the following error message:

"Could not find RIFF or WAVE identifiers (not a Waveform file)"

I tried all export settings in Audacity that I know of, what could I be doing wrong here?

I did everything correctly, I even checked using an hex editor and the identifiers are there.
[image: File in an hex editor]

This issue happens with any file format I try. FOpen was able to read the identifier bytes perfectly too, what could the issue be?

I am using gcc to compile on an Ubuntu machine. I used the package manager to install everything.

The code:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_mixer.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    int Mixer = Mix_OpenAudio( 44100, MIX_DEFAULT_FORMAT, 2, 2048 );
    if(Mixer < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Mixer wasn't initialized.";
        return 0;
    }
    if( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_AUDIO ))
    {
        std::cout << "Sdl audio wasn't initialized.";
        return 0;
    }

    Mix_Chunk *mc = Mix_LoadWAV("YouGotMail.wav");
    
    if (!mc)
    {
        std::cout << std::string(std::string("Failed to load audio YouGotMail.wav.\n") + Mix_GetError()).c_str() << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Using ldd on the executable gives me this output:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe219be000)
        libSDL2-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f569c0eb000)
        libSDL2_image-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2_image-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f569c0c8000)
        libSDL_mixer-1.2.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL_mixer-1.2.so.0 (0x00007f569c073000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f569be91000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f569be76000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f569bc84000)
        libasound.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2 (0x00007f569bb87000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f569ba38000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f569ba32000)
        libpulse.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpulse.so.0 (0x00007f569b9dd000)
        libX11.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f569b8a0000)
        libXext.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007f569b88b000)
        libXcursor.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcursor.so.1 (0x00007f569b87c000)
        libXinerama.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXinerama.so.1 (0x00007f569b877000)
        libXi.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6 (0x00007f569b865000)
        libXrandr.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrandr.so.2 (0x00007f569b858000)
        libXss.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXss.so.1 (0x00007f569b853000)
        libXxf86vm.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1 (0x00007f569b84c000)
        libwayland-egl.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1 (0x00007f569b845000)
        libwayland-client.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-client.so.0 (0x00007f569b834000)
        libwayland-cursor.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-cursor.so.0 (0x00007f569b829000)
        libxkbcommon.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxkbcommon.so.0 (0x00007f569b7e7000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f569b7c4000)
        libpng16.so.16 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16 (0x00007f569b78c000)
        libjpeg.so.8 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8 (0x00007f569b705000)
        libtiff.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.5 (0x00007f569b684000)
        libwebp.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebp.so.6 (0x00007f569b61a000)
        libSDL-1.2.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL-1.2.so.0 (0x00007f569b57e000)
        libmikmod.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmikmod.so.3 (0x00007f569b33b000)
        libfluidsynth.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfluidsynth.so.2 (0x00007f569b269000)
        libvorbisfile.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbisfile.so.3 (0x00007f569b25c000)
        libFLAC.so.8 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libFLAC.so.8 (0x00007f569b21e000)
        libmad.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmad.so.0 (0x00007f569b1fb000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f569c293000)
        libpulsecommon-13.99.so => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pulseaudio/libpulsecommon-13.99.so (0x00007f569b179000)
        libdbus-1.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3 (0x00007f569b128000)
        libxcb.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f569b0fc000)
        libXrender.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1 (0x00007f569aef2000)
        libXfixes.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00007f569aeea000)
        libffi.so.7 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.7 (0x00007f569aede000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f569aec2000)
        libzstd.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzstd.so.1 (0x00007f569ae17000)
        liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f569adee000)
        libjbig.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjbig.so.0 (0x00007f569abe0000)
        libpulse-simple.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpulse-simple.so.0 (0x00007f569abd9000)
        libcaca.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcaca.so.0 (0x00007f569ab0d000)
        libopenal.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenal.so.1 (0x00007f569aa25000)
        libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f569a8fa000)
        libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f569a8f4000)
        libjack.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjack.so.0 (0x00007f569a8a8000)
        libsndfile.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsndfile.so.1 (0x00007f569a82a000)
        libreadline.so.8 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.8 (0x00007f569a7da000)
        libinstpatch-1.0.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libinstpatch-1.0.so.2 (0x00007f569a71f000)
        libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f569a6bd000)
        libvorbis.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbis.so.0 (0x00007f569a68f000)
        libogg.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libogg.so.0 (0x00007f569a682000)
        libsystemd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so.0 (0x00007f569a5d3000)
        libwrap.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwrap.so.0 (0x00007f569a5c7000)
        libasyncns.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasyncns.so.0 (0x00007f569a3bf000)
        libapparmor.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapparmor.so.1 (0x00007f569a3aa000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f569a39f000)
        libXau.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f569a399000)
        libXdmcp.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f569a391000)
        libslang.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libslang.so.2 (0x00007f569a09a000)
        libncursesw.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncursesw.so.6 (0x00007f569a05e000)
        libtinfo.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.6 (0x00007f569a02e000)
        libsndio.so.7.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsndio.so.7.0 (0x00007f569a01d000)
        libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f5699faa000)
        libvorbisenc.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbisenc.so.2 (0x00007f5699eff000)
        liblz4.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so.1 (0x00007f5699edc000)
        libgcrypt.so.20 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20 (0x00007f5699dbe000)
        libnsl.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl.so.1 (0x00007f5699da1000)
        libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f5699d85000)
        libbsd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0x00007f5699d6b000)
        libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x00007f5699d46000)
```

Comment: Can't reproduce neither on gentoo with latest SDL nor on ubuntu 21.10. The problem is not with the code in question (or a wav file), and it is really hard to guess what could go wrong on your system. What's your build command? If you use `sdl2-config`, what's its output? Add output of `ldd ./your_program_name` and `strace ./your_program_name` to question (if you don't have strace - install it, package have the same name), then maaaaaaaybe we could figure something out.

Comment: @keltar I'm using g++ as the build command with ofast optimization flag which does not seem to be the problem. What do you mean by "use sdl2-config"? I added the ldd output to the post but the strace output doesn't even fit in my terminal.

Comment: It looks suspicious to me that the executable links both to `libSDL2-2.0` and `libSDL-1.2`. And only to `libSDL_mixer-1.2` and not `libSDL2_mixer-2.0`. But then again I've never used SDL, so maybe that's normal?

Comment: Yeah what @danadam said, that's definitely not normal. Looks like you linked with `SDL_mixer`, which is older library intended to be used with SDL 1.2. For SDL2 you should link with `SDL2_mixer`. With that library combination I actually get the same error as you've described, because it calls wrong functions.

Comment: I was stuck on this for over a month thank you so much for helping, I wished someone asked me to try that earlier instead of ignoring me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I was having was that I was linking the old sdl mixer which doesnt work with SDL2, adding lSDL2_mixer library to my make file fixed the error, thank you so much keltar and danadam for pointing this out.